# How do you restart Samba on OSX 10.6.7?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, samba

How do you restart Samba on OSX 10.6.7?  I've looked everywhere can't fine any docs.

Reason for asking is that on occasion Samba just hangs and I have to forcibly restart the mac to fix it.  (restart command just hangs the mac)

Answer (score 2):

On a terminal, `sudo killall smbd` will terminate all smbd instances.
They will be respawned on demand accoring to my tests (i.e. kill all smbd, then try to browse the services with `smbclient -L hostname`, and the daemons are restarted automagically).

You can check for `smbd` processes easily with `ps uax | grep smbd`

Edit: if you need to really assassinate blocked smbd processes, use `killall -9 smbd` (which is [not recommended](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OSX/8/smbd/), see section on signals )

Comment: There are no smbd processes running on 10.6.7.  I've found plenty of suggestions for older version,s but 10.6.7 does it different somehow and I haven't found out how (and how to restart it).  If the Samba is locked up, smbclient will lock up too and the terminal will also die.

Comment: Gonna have to agree that 10.6.7's smb client locks up.